# How many hits can google drive bare if i use it as cloud database?

Tags: database, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api, google-drive-realtime-api

I am working on an app where there is 1M hits every day.I want to use google drive as database .Can google drive bare this much traffic??

Comment: I've done this before but only where performance was not a concern. It will be slow. That is not its purpose. You should look into Amazon s3 as it would benefit you at the scale of your app.

Comment: I am just fetching name and vediourl from database does performance issue occurred in this minor data?? If yes does 1M users traffic bared by google drive??

Comment: I don't know your tech stack but GDrive was slower than Sqlite for me. If I had to guess, this will probably be the bottleneck in your architecture but you can always do it asynchronously so it might be fine depending on your need. It doesn't matter how much data you're getting, it's more about the access speed itself. Once the request has been processed, getting more data shouldn't be any slower (unless you're considering the propagation delay, which won't be the bottleneck with Drive) Test it and see if it is fine for your use case.

Comment: ok can you guide me about Amazon s3 for my usecase how much cost would i get monthly for 1M users.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly discourage using Drive as a database. Since that behaviour isn't its aim, it may create a noticeable bottleneck in your project. I recommend using [Cloud SQL](https://cloud.google.com/sql/) as an alternative. Nevertheless, these are the Drive API quota limits extracted from `Google Cloud Platform ⮞ Navigation menu ⮞ IAM & Admin ⮞ Quotas`:

[image: Drive API quota limits]

If you really want to use Drive as a database, you must keep in mind those usage limits. I'll take for granted that you need to read a different row from the database per each hit, so no cache is involved here. In that scenario, assuming ideal user distribution, the project would cap at 8,640,000 daily hits (expecting ten different concurrent accounts to interact with the database in order to provide the data).

Comment: The link you gave is for Google Docs API.

Comment: Hi there @tsiki! Thank you so much for your observation, I've already updated my answer to reflect it.